# after submit popup show again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form which is linked to post php

```
<form action="newsletter.php" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="name" id="wd1_nlpopup_name" placeholder="Name" value="" class="textinput" tabindex="500">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="wd1_nlpopup_mail" placeholder="Your email" value="" class="textinput" tabindex="501">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-orange btn-large" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

and this javascript file which popup the form

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var wd1_nlpopup_expires = $("#wd1_nlpopup").data("expires");
    var wd1_nlpopup_delay = $("#wd1_nlpopup").data("delay") * 1000;

    $('#wd1_nlpopup_close').on('click', function(e){
        $.cookie('wd1_nlpopup', 'closed', { expires: wd1_nlpopup_expires, path: '/' });
        $('#wd1_nlpopup,#wd1_nlpopup_overlay').fadeOut(200);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

        $('#submit').on('submit', function(e){
        $.cookie('wd1_nlpopup', 'submited', { expires: wd1_nlpopup_expires, path: '/' });
        $('#wd1_nlpopup,#wd1_nlpopup_overlay').fadeOut(200);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    if($.cookie('wd1_nlpopup') != 'closed' || 'submited'){
        setTimeout(wd1_open_nlpopup, wd1_nlpopup_delay);
    }
```

When data is submited data is in mysql database but popup show again i trying to use `onsubmit` with function but same result or popup don`t show but data is not in the database.Thank you

Comment: Have you considered changing your logic to post the form using AJAX?

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log("wd1_nlpopup", $.cookie('wd1_nlpopup'))` before your final `if` statement?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is preventing the form from being submitted.  Remove that line at least if you want it to actually post the form.

Comment: What is the value of `$("#wd1_nlpopup").data("expires");`?  Your cookie could be getting set to an expires value of `undefined`.

Comment: console.log("wd1_nlpopup", $.cookie('wd1_nlpopup')) I get  wd1_nlpopup submited and popup show again also i try with post from ajax but then popup don`t show at all when load the page

Comment: SeanKendle when i remove e.preventDefault(); how to prevent popup to popup show again

Comment: Change your line to this: `if($.cookie('wd1_nlpopup') != 'closed' && $.cookie('wd1_nlpopup') != 'submited'){`

Comment: The `|| 'submited'` is evaluated as "truthy", therefore that statement, since it's an OR, is always truthy, thus that pop up will always show.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `e.preventDefault();` from your on submit function.

Change your `if` statement at the end to this: 
`if($.cookie('wd1_nlpopup') != 'closed' && $.cookie('wd1_nlpopup') != 'submited'){`

The `|| 'submited'` clause is evaluated as "truthy", therefore that statement, since it's an `OR`, is always truthy, thus that pop up will always show.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered  true when
>   evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are
>   defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and
>   NaN).
>
> JavaScript uses type coercion in Boolean contexts.
>
> Examples of truthy values in JavaScript (which will translate to true
>   and thus execute the if block):
>
> if (true)
>
> if ({})
>
> if ([])
>
> if (42)
>
> if ("foo")
>
> if (new Date())
>
> if (-42)
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you it`s work i change also #submit with 'form'